# Weird problem. My left arrow key is not working and sometimes muting sound

Tags: linux, fedora, xorg, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

My left arrow key is not working as intended.

In KDE, it mutes the sound.

In Awesome Window manager, it does nothing.

Here's my `00-keyboard.conf` file :
I have tired to comment out `XkbModel`, `XkbLayout` and `XkbVariant` options too but no good

```
#This file was generated by the Anaconda installer
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier  "keyboard"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        Option         "XkbModel"   "evdev"
        Option         "XkbLayout"     "us,ara"
        Option         "XkbVariant"    ",qwerty_digits"
        Option          "XkbOptions"    "grp:alt_shift_toggle,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,"
EndSection

Section "ServerFlags"
        Option  "DontZap" "false"
EndSection
```

Here's my `.Xmodmap` file (notice that the left arrow is not working with or without the xmodmap :

```
keycode 113 = 0x1008FF12 (the actual mute button)
keycode 224 = 0x1008FF03 (lowering brightness button - not working too)
```

Any help would be appreciated. this is really strange. I'm using Fedora 18.

Comment: Ok, the keycode 113 according to `showkey` is the f11 key which also is a multimedia key (Mute). So i tried to map it to the sound mute functionality. But when i press it, nothing happens. What happens In KDE, when i press the left arrow, mute functionality gets activated.
(and i just did `xmodmap .Xmodmap` so when i restart X, it should be restored to defaults - which is, the left arrow key moves the pointer to the left, and the multimedia button has no functionality yet)

Comment: @don_crissti Ah, that did it, the left key was actually `113` and the mute key was `121`. corrected it and the left key works, but still the mute key doesn't work.

Comment: @don_crissti I've worked it out, I needed `xbindkeys` to assign what `XF86AudioMute` do. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to see if the key gives the expected keycode with `xev` and pressing the key to see the actual keycode it generates. I have seen 'working' keyboards that had some fluid spilled over them generate wrong (and multiple) keycodes.

It looks like you are in 'us' mode with your keyboard. On that my <kbd>←</kbd> generates keycode 113, so the muting does not seem be completely unexpected given your `.Xmodmap`.

Make sure to restart X (logout of the Windowmanager and log back in), to make sure changes to .Xmodmap take effect.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange, when i try using `showkey` the left arrow gives me `105` and the actual mute button gives `113`

Comment: Ok i tried with `xev`. The left arrow key gives me `113` and the mute key gives `121`. I changed it in the .Xmodmap file, but unfortunately the problem still occurs.

Comment: I've worked it out, just restarted X and applied `.Xmodmap` after the modifications. Also i needed xbindkeys to assign what XF86AudioMute do. Thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry I should have included that you need to restart X if you change the .Xmodmap. I am going to add it so people don't have to wade through the comments. You can of course add an answer yourself as well with that info.

Comment: Could you add the `xbindkeys` solution to your answer. So that it becomes complete in regard to all the difficulties that I've faced through the whole process because your answer really helped. Thanks

Comment: @RafaelAdel Linux key codes shown by `showkey` and X key codes shown by `xev` are different. Also, you don't need to restart X after changing `.Xmodmap`, just reload it with `xmodmap .Xmodmap`. A few applications may need to be restarted if you've changed modifiers.